# Change bullet style for list items in a bulleted list

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am currently filling a bulleted list using the code below.  It works fine but what I'd like to know is if it's possible to change the bullet style for a single list item if it meets some condition.  Can this be done or do all the bullets in one list have to be the same?  Any help is appreciated.

```
List<string> EventInfo = new List<string>();

//add list content here

for (int i = 0; i < EventInfo.Count; i++)
{
     ListItem stuff = new ListItem();
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EventInfo[i]))
     {
          stuff.Text = EventInfo[i];
          //check if condition is met and change bullet style for this item     
          BulletedList.Items.Add(stuff);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to define your css-style:

`li.active { list-style-type:square; }`

After that, you'll need to make sure your list-items actually *get* the required class based on your condition.

```
for (int i = 0; i < EventInfo.Count; i++)
{
  ListItem stuff = new ListItem();
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EventInfo[i]))
  {
    stuff.Text = EventInfo[i];
    //check if condition is met and change bullet style for this item     
    if(condition)
    {
      stuff.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
    }
    BulletedList.Items.Add(stuff);
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a way to do this with css.  `Attributes.Add` is what I needed, thanks for the speedy response!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS, like this:

```
li
{
   list-style-type:square;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using c# you can use below code:

```
BulletedList.Style.Add("list-style-type", "Circle");
```